# Flutter[Android]: Not able to release App with Manage External Storage Permission

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-external-storage

We need to allow users to store files in the external storage and for the same, we use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in our application.

Ideally for the android SDK version 30 and above we are using `Permission.manageExternalStorage` and using `Permission.storage` for android SDK versions lower than 30 as shown in the below code

```
  // This func is added to access scope storage to export csv files
  static Future<bool> externalStoragePermission(BuildContext context) async {
    final androidVersion = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;

    if ((androidVersion.version.sdkInt ?? 0) >= 30) {
      return await checkManageStoragePermission(context);
    } else {
      return await checkStoragePermission(context);
    }
  }

  static Future<bool> checkManageStoragePermission(BuildContext context) async {
    return (await Permission.manageExternalStorage.isGranted ||
        await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request().isGranted);
  }

  static Future<bool> checkStoragePermission(BuildContext context,
      {String? storageTitle, String? storageSubMessage}) async {
    if (await Permission.storage.isGranted ||
        await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      openBottomSheet(
        title: storageTitle ?? Str.of(context).storagePermissionRequired,
        message: storageSubMessage ?? Str.of(context).storageSubMessage,
      ).show(context);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

With the above implementation, everything worked fine while the development and internal release but the Google play console reject the application with the below rejections(Also we have submitted the reason as well for manage_storage permission).

[image]

Comment: Now on Android 13, you need to add new permissions to access the storage depending on files you want to retrieve : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and applied the below solution for the above issue in my project.

1. We have to use [SAF(Storage Access Framework)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) on behalf of the storage permission [shared_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_storage) which will allow us to grant the permission for the specific directory in the shared storage and we can store the files over there. I have also added the code sample for the same below.

```
  Future<void> exportFile({
    required String csvData,
    required String fileName,
  }) async {
    Uri? selectedUriDir;
    final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final scopeStoragePersistUrl = pref.getString('scopeStoragePersistUrl');
   
    // Check User has already grant permission to any directory or not
    if (scopeStoragePersistUrl != null &&
        await isPersistedUri(Uri.parse(scopeStoragePersistUrl)) &&
        (await exists(Uri.parse(scopeStoragePersistUrl)) ?? false)) {
      selectedUriDir = Uri.parse(scopeStoragePersistUrl);
    } else {
      selectedUriDir = await openDocumentTree();
      await pref.setString('scopeStoragePersistUrl', selectedUriDir.toString());
    }
    if (selectedUriDir == null) {
      return false;
    }
    try {
      final existingFile = await findFile(selectedUriDir, fileName);
      if (existingFile != null && existingFile.isFile) {
        debugPrint("Found existing file ${existingFile.uri}");
        await delete(existingFile.uri);
      }
      final newDocumentFile = await createFileAsString(
        selectedUriDir,
        mimeType: AppConstants.csvMimeTypeWhileExport,
        content: csvData,
        displayName: fileName,
      );
      return newDocumentFile != null;
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Exception while create new file: ${e.toString()}");
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this issue

properly tested in android level less then 11 or greater then 11

First please check this is that android device on your onpressd button like this

```
if(Platform.isAndroid)
{
  downloadAndSavePDF('your network link');
}
```

=> and then method

```
Future<void> downloadAndSavePDF(String pdfUrl, String fileName) async {
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(pdfUrl));
if (response.contentLength == 0) {
  return Future.value(null);
}
try {
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Get the downloads directory
    Directory downloadsDirectory =
        Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download/');
    final File file = File('${downloadsDirectory.path}/$fileName');
    if (file.existsSync()) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      CustomSnakeBar(errorMessage: 'File already downloaded')
          .snakeBar(context);
      return;
    }
    // Write the PDF content to the file
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    Navigator.pop(context);
    CustomSnakeBar(
            errorMessage: 'PDF downloaded', colorText: ConstColor.green)
        .snakeBar(context);
  } else {
    CustomSnakeBar(errorMessage: ConstString.somethingWentWrong)
        .snakeBar(context);
  }
} catch (e) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
  CustomSnakeBar(errorMessage: ConstString.somethingWentWrong)
      .snakeBar(context);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If is not an app that needs the to access the device external storage (e.g antivirus app) and you want to download a file in Flutter, you might just use the package [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to use your app specific directory provider by android during installation. use this to download file

```
final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(URL!));
final appDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File file = File(appDir.path + '/${filename}');
try {
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  print('success');
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}
```

or you can use [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package to downlaod the file it manages everything you need to create the file out of the box for you

```
try {
  Response response = await Dio().download(
    downloadURL!,
    appDir.path + '/${filename}',
    onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
      // You can handle download progress here
      print('Received: $received, Total: $total');
    },
  );
  print('success');
} catch (e) {
  print('Error: $e');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> > We need to allow users to store files in the external storage and for the same, we use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in our application.

You do not need that permission to create your own subdirs in public directories like Download, Documents, DCIM, Pictures and so.

Also you do not need that permission to create files in those directories and subdirs.

Comment: I agreed I don't need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to create the new directory in scope storage but what is the way using which I can Create dir and save file over there in flutter?

Comment: You want to create files in public external storage. You do that the same way as when you create files in internal or app specific external storage. Only the used path is different. Take the right path.

Comment: Actually, don't use this permission until your app falls in the following category, Otherwise, the Play console will reject your app. 
 File managers,
Backup and restore apps,
Anti-virus apps,
Document management apps,
On-device file search,
Disk and file encryption,
Device-to-device data migration

Comment: @DhavalKansara can you help me how to access specific folder from external/internal storage using flutter? Because if using full external store then app getting rejected