# How can I open file (that is not image, video or audio) through my Flutter App in Android 13?

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, notifications

I need to open a file that is an attachment in my app, those file could be any type really, images, videos, pdfs, excel files...
Android 13 has permissions for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO and READ_MEDIA_AUDIO, and can request them with **permission_handler**:

`[Permission.photos, Permission.videos, Permission.audio].request()`

After that when I can open the downloaded file from notification with **open_file** package:

`OpenFile.open(path)`

But when I try to open a pdf file, it just doesn't work. It gives me an error:
*Permission denied: android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE flutter*

That permission is permanently denied in settings, and that is not intuitive to user to send him to the app whenever I need to open a file from notification. Also I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783148/flutterandroid-not-able-to-release-app-with-manage-external-storage-permissio) that I can't put it in manifest because it will be rejected by the Play Store.

If you can help me out, here is the code below:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:device_info_plus/device_info_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';
import 'package:pagedesk/data/model/ticket/attachemnt_item.dart';
import 'package:pagedesk/data/network/firebase_api.dart';
import 'package:pagedesk/utils/Utils.dart';
import 'package:pagedesk/view_model/ticket_attachemnts_view_model.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class Notifications {
  int maxProgress = 5;
  bool isCompleted = false;

  Future getDownloadNotification(
      AttachemntItem item,
      String downloadingText,
      String downloadCompletedText,
      String downoadFaildMessage,
      String cantOpenFailMessage,
      TicketAttachemntsViewModel viewModel) async {
    final AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'name',
      'name',
      channelDescription: 'progress channel description',
      channelShowBadge: false,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      showProgress: false,
    );
    final NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidNotificationDetails);

    String newPath = "";

    Directory directory;
    try {
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        if (await requestStoragePermissions()) {
          directory = (await getExternalStorageDirectory())!;
          print(directory);
          List<String> paths = directory.path.split("/");
          for (int x = 1; x < paths.length; x++) {
            String folder = paths[x];
            if (folder != "Android") {
              newPath += "/$folder";
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }
          newPath = "$newPath/Download";
          directory = Directory(newPath);
        } else {
          return;
        }
      } else {
        if (await _requestPermission(Permission.storage)) {
          directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }

      if (!await directory.exists()) {
        await directory.create(recursive: true);
      }

      String filename = item.name;
      String path = directory.path;
      print('FILENAME: $filename');
      print('OATH: $path');

      File file = File('$path/$filename');
      if (await file.exists()) {
        int suffix = 1;
        String newFileName;
        while (await file.exists()) {
          newFileName =
              '${filename.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\..+'), '')}($suffix)${filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))}';

          file = File('$path/$newFileName');
          suffix++;
        }
      } else {
        print("File doesn't exist");
      }

      FirebaseApi.localNotifications.show(
          item.id,
          item.name,
          isCompleted ? downloadCompletedText : downloadingText,
          notificationDetails,
          payload: newPath);
      viewModel.getAttachment(item).then((value) => {
            if (value != null)
              {
                file.writeAsBytes(value),
                isCompleted = true,
                FirebaseApi.localNotifications.cancel(item.id),
                FirebaseApi.localNotifications.show(item.id, item.name,
                    downloadCompletedText, notificationDetails,
                    payload: file.path)
              }
            else
              {
                isCompleted = false,
                FirebaseApi.localNotifications.cancel(item.id),
                FirebaseApi.localNotifications.show(item.id, item.name,
                    downoadFaildMessage, notificationDetails,
                    payload: null)
              }
          });
    } catch (e) {
      print('ERROR');
    }
  }
}

void openFile(String path, String cantOpenFileMessage) async {
  try {
    final result = await OpenFile.open(path);
    if (result.type == ResultType.done) {
      print('File opened successfully');
    } else if (result.type == ResultType.noAppToOpen) {
      Utils.toastMessage(cantOpenFileMessage);
    } else {
      Utils.toastMessage("Can't open file throgh this app.");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error opening file: $e');
  }
}

Future<bool> _requestPermission(Permission permission) async {
  if (await permission.isGranted) {
    return true;
  } else if (await permission.isPermanentlyDenied) {
    openAppSettings();
    return false;
  } else {
    var result = await permission.request();
    if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

Future<bool> requestStoragePermissions() async {
  List<Permission> permissions = [];
  final deviceInfo = await DeviceInfoPlugin().androidInfo;

  if (deviceInfo.version.sdkInt > 32) {
    permissions = [Permission.photos, Permission.videos, Permission.audio];
  } else {
    permissions = [Permission.storage];
  }
  Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await permissions.request();
  return !statuses.containsKey(false);
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: I have an application in production both on android and ios and it's using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. You will need to add justifications of why you use it but you are totally free to use it and it will not stop you from publishing it

Comment: Ok, but did you get it to ask for MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, because when I try to request it it says Permanently denied by default.

Comment: `an attachment in my app` Sorry what would that be? I know emails van come and go with attachments. But apps?

Comment: Who downloaded that file? Please start your post with this info. We have to know if your app created the file or another app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (not 100%) that as it's a new permission that is by default denied, you need to make the user change it manually via its settings, even if it's not intuitive for the developper like you said. I dont know if you have seen that you can programmatically open the setting page so it's easier for the user.

Comment: On an Android 13 device the permissions READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VIDEO and READ_MEDIA_AUDIO are all not needed to read files created by the app itself.

Comment: You dont need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Dont talk about it. Its confusing.

Comment: Requesting permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE on an Android 13 devices makes no sense. Your app has by default write permission in all public directories on external storage.

Comment: Instead of spamming the conversation we're having can you edit your previous comments, it would be more readable. As shown on his code, he's trying to open a file from the download folder so it's not a file that is necessarily created by the app, thus the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is relevant

Comment: Do not only use file.exists() but also file.canRead() before you try to read a file.

Comment: `You dont need MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Dont talk about it. Its confusing. ` How you're so sure about this @blackapps ?

Comment: Sorry guys for late replies. I actually get the bytes for the file from an endpoint from my backend, and this code shows notification while it is downloading and writing bytes to a file and then shows another notification as an indicator that download is completed and that file can be accessed by the user.

Comment: @blackapps By 'attachments', I meant files that serve as attachments on posts in my app, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Hedwin I saw that I can open the setting app programatically, but I thought that it can be done in more 'intuitive' way. If you want, post that as an anwer on this post, I will accept it if nobody comes up with something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure (not 100%) that as it's a new permission that is by default denied, you need to make the user change it manually via its settings, even if it's not intuitive for users like you said.

I dont know if you have seen that you can programmatically open the setting page so it's easier for the user.

Unfortunately I don't think that there is a better solution than that.

Answer (score 0):

Now if you said that your app is downloading data itself and creating a file for it itself then you dont need any permission to do so on Android 13+ devices. And certainly not the manage external storage.

And once your app created and wrote the file it is automatically permitted to read the file using the same path.